# Looking for sample BlackBerry projects

Tags: open-source, blackberry

I'm looking for well written open-source projects for BlackBerry which I could use as RI samples. I've downloaded sources of Wordpress client for BlackBerry, application is damn good. Any other apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/51-updated-open-source-blackberry-apps-develop-your-own.html

They are GNU GPL Open source.

Also search SourceForge for 'BlackBerry':

http://sourceforge.net/search/?type_of_search=soft&words=blackberry

Comment: I'll start with your comment ;)